# PM2 and Nginx: 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, pm2

I've been trying to deploy my Node project on a brand new DO droplet, but i'm having some problems with PM2.

My steps are a follows:

1. Node came installed on the Droplet image (Ubuntu, Node v4.4.4)
2. Installed PM2 globally
3. Setup Nginx to reverse proxy 127.0.0.1:3000
4. Cloned my project and did npm install

All i get is Nginx complaining about a 502 Bad Gateway.

If i look at the Nginx error.log i get this:

> connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to
>   upstream, client: ***client.ip***, server: ***my.server***, request:
>   "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host:
>   "***my.server***"

PM2 doesn't have much to say about anything. Nothing in *pm2 logs* and status is **online**.

I tried skipping PM2 and just doing npm start which worked perfectly. I also tried setting up a dummy hello world application instead, and using that with PM2 - it also worked.

So this is currently where i'm at:

- My project + PM2: doesn't work.
- My project without PM2: works.
- Hello World app + PM2: works.

I'm not really sure where to go from here.. I could just skip PM2 and use node, but i do want the features of PM2.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure your app is actually starting on port 3000?

Comment: Well.. it's probably isn't as Nginx is complaining. I just have no idea how i can check. PM2 says that's everything is all good and online and the logs are clean.

Comment: My problem actually turned out to so silly actually, I noticed that 502s were given only for POST requests that do modify the database, which was a sqllite file within the app directory which caused PM2 to restart the app before sending the response when that file was written because it was run with --watch flag. on other cases it can be the --kill-timeout that is too short for you response time, which also causes the app restart.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just had to start PM2 with ***bin/www*** instead of ***app.js***. Express generator and everything...

Comment: Have had an incredibly horrific afternoon trying to solve this problem. Would love to know why bin/www worked while app.js did not.

Comment: Thank you. Worked with my MEAN application.

Comment: Also ensure NODE_ENV=production

Comment: what is bin/www and where is it located ?

Comment: @PeterMoses and anyone else interested: `bin/www` is relative your application directory. Example: my project is in `/var/www/my-project/`. From `my-project`, I ran `pm2 start node ./bin/www` and my application is now served as expected.

Comment: work in 2022!!!

Comment: Relative paths are always a pain!! Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Nginx has a directive called proxy_read_timeout which defaults to 60 secs. It determines how long nginx will wait to get the response to a request. In nginx. conf file, setting proxy_read_timeout to 120 secs solved our problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I renamed `app.js` to `project.js` or something and it works.

Answer (score -3):

This is some issue with the node installation. Delete the node_modules folder, install again using npm and start the project using pm2.

pm2 kill

rm -rf node_modules

npm i

pm2 start bin/www