# How can I change the IP address in an a ETIMEDOUT error on my VuejS app running via pm2?

Tags: vue.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, pm2

I am running a **Laravel** app on an **Ubuntu** ec2 instance using **Nginx**.

I have a front-end app built using **Vue.js** running via **pm2** that uses API's from the Laravel app.

I recently had an issue where I had to swap the elastic IP being used on AWS and have since been trying to get it working again with a new IP.

I only get 502 and now Nginx 504 errors and have tried everything that I can find (mostly about increasing fastcgi times). The errors that I can see are below (with URLs and IPs redacted).

My pm2 log:

```
ERROR  connect ETIMEDOUT <the old wrong IP>:443
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1191:14)
```

My nginx error log:

```
[error] 29592#29592: *83 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading 
response header from upstream, client: <my computers IP>, server: <the site URL>, 
request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "<the site URL>"
```

How can I update the wrong IP listed in my pm2 error log?

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37410822/pm2-and-nginx-502-bad-gateway) question, but am honestly not sure exactly how to "start" pm2 in the way suggested.